# How in PhpStorm 2019.3 to open view by ref in control?

Tags: phpstorm

Working with laravel 8 app if there is a way in PhpStorm 2019.3.4
having view reference in the control like :
return view('admin.users.index',

to open view by clicking on view name ?

I have several plugins installed as : Laravel (by Daniel Espendiller ) , LaravelStorm 1.1
but I did not get functionality I wrote above.

Can I add this functionality?

Thanks!

Comment: I was wondering if you have already tried the Laravel Idea plugin. It is a paid one but at the moment, it has the best Laravel support available.

Comment: Thanks for your ref. Has it functionality I search ?

Comment: `return view('admin.users.index')` should be supported by the original Laravel plugin. At very least such `Ctrl+Click` navigation still works fine for me in PhpStorm 2020.3.3 (code: `return view('admin::dashboard.contact-us.index', $data);`)

Comment: But seems not for my PhpStorm 2019.3.4  ?

Comment: Sorry, no solid comments on over a year old version. Not going to install and try it myself. 1) Could be the plugin itself (e.g. something that was fixed since then but your IDE does not allow to install such version -- better check versions for that); 2) Possibly some interference from another plugin; 3) Could be Laravel 8 version differences (that project of mine is still on v6)...